# Use same db table from different entities in Entity Framework- Code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have used Entity Framework database first few times. Now, I'm trying to approach code first. I am little bit confused in some places. Lets say, I would like to have two classes- `ApplicationUser` & `CurrentUser`. All of these classes intended to use the same database table **Users**. The structure of Users table looks like-

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UserId | FullName | Designation | LoginName | LoginPassword | CreatedDateTime | IsActive | FewOtherFields |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here are the classes details-

```
//Will be used to add,edit, delete records for new user.
ApplicationUser
{
   UserId 
   FullName
   Designation 
   LoginName 
   LoginPassword 
   CreatedDateTime 
   IsActive
   ...
   OtherProperties
   ...
}

//Will be used to login and other purposes.
CurrentUser
{
   UserId 
   FullName
   Designation 
   LoginName 
   LoginPassword  
   IsActive
}
```

Might be this is an easy thing, or there are tricky techniques to achieve this. Any help?

Comment: CurrentUser is an ApplicationUser. What's the reasoning behind having a CurrentUser class? Is your intention to hide some of the properties?

Comment: Why do you want two different classes to represent the same thing? If you must use `CurrentUser` then project `ApplicationUser` to it (e.g. with a `.Select()`)

Comment: @Juan- Property hiding is a reason. And few other issues are also there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Table per Hierarchy* inheritance strategy:

```
public class CurrentUser
{
    //some properties
}

public class ApplicationUser : CurrentUser
{
    //additional properties
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CurrentUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
IQuerable<CurrentUser> currentUsers = context.Users;
IQuerable<ApplicationUser> applicationUsers = context.Users.OfType<ApplicationUser>();
```